# How can i get the client IP address in Flask running on an Azure Linux Web App?

Tags: python, azure, flask

I am running a flask site on an Azure Linux Web App. I've come to a point where I need to know the client ip address. I have read many threads that talk about accessing the client IP address when behind a proxy and that you must update your nginx configuration file to pass this information through the proxy, however, I don't think my Azure Linux web app is running an nginx web server.

How can I tell which web server my Azure Linux Web App is running and how can I start to look for the client IP address in the python code of my Flask app?

Comment: Have you at least tried `request.remote_addr`?

Comment: @noslenkwah yes, I have tried request.remote_addr and other request environ variables. It seems for any of them to be populated I need to update my unknown configuration to have the values passed through from the proxy server. But how do I discover what my proxy server is and what web server I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure Linux Web App, it will change the request from the Internet through the reverse proxy. So you need to use the `request` package to get the client. The example code here:

```
clinet_ips = request.headers.getlist("X-Forwarded-For")
```